# Как вызвать функцию при нажатии на кнопку в discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я пытаюсь сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку выполнялась другая, уже готовая функция. К примеру если нажать на кнопку 1 - сработает функция Hi. Как её вызвать?

```
@client.command()
 async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi')

 @client.command(pass_context = True)
 async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
      embed=discord.Embed(title="все возможные пути"),
      components=[
        Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="1")
      ]
        )
    response = await client.wait_for("button_click")
    if response.channel == ctx.channel:
            #---------------------#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все действия, которые должны вызываться  при помощи `команды`, `нажатия кнопки` или просто из кода лучше выносить в отдельную асинхронную функцию:

Тогда можно будет просто вызывать их из функций команды и кнопки:

```py
async def _Hi(ctx):
   . . .

@client.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
   await _Hi(ctx)

# и при помощи кнопки тоже самое
@client.command()
async def . . .(ctx):
   response = await client.wait_for("button_click")
   if response.channel == ctx.channel:
       await _Hi(ctx)
```